# 7z command to create a XZ file

Tags: compression, archive, 7z, xz

The man page says 7z tool supports *7z, LZMA2, XZ, ZIP, Zip64, CAB, RAR, ARJ, GZIP, BZIP2, TAR, CPIO, RPM, ISO,* most filesystem images and *DEB* formats.

And it says we could pass the type as `-t{Type}`. The following command is success.

```
7z a -tzip archive.zip dir1 dir2 file1 file2
```

But I can't archive the files into `.xz` using the following command.

```
7z a -txz archive.zip dir1 dir2 file1 file2
```

```
$ 7z a -txz archive.xz dir1 dir2 file1 file2

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz (806E9),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive:
2 folders, 7 files, 196192711 bytes (188 MiB)

Creating archive: archive.xz

Items to compress: 9



System ERROR:
E_INVALIDARG
```

Anything I am doing wrong here? How to create `.xz` file using `7z` command?

**EDIT:**
The following command successful.

```
7z a -txz archive archive.tar
```

Does it mean we can use `-txz` or `-tbzip2` on only archive files as we can't directly use compression on files without archiving the files first?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on finding the solution youself. However, please don't edit your question to contain the answer - write [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like gzip (`.gz`) and bzip2 (`.bz2`), but unlike zip and rar, xz is a compression format, not an archive format. You can compress one file:

```
7z a -txz foo.xz foo
```

This is equivalent to `xz foo`.

Typically, to make a compressed archive, you make a tar archive and compress it. You can make a compressed archive with 7z, but as far as I can tell, you can't do it in a single step: you have to create the tar first, then compress it. (7z does know how to read from a compressed archive directly.) You can do that in a pipeline.

```
set -o pipefail
7z a -ttar -so archive.tar.xz dir1 dir2 file1 file2 | 7z a -txz -si archive.tar.xz
```

As far as I know, `archive.tar.xz` in the left-hand command is ignored (`-so` tells 7z to write to standard output), but it's still necessary.

With a pipeline, beware that in sh, if the tar creation fails, for example because a file can't be read, then the pipeline command won't fail. Ksh, bash and zsh have an option `pipefail` to make the whole command fail.

It's a lot simpler to call `tar` directly. Most modern tar implementations can create gz, bz2 and xz compressed archives.

```
tar -cJf archive.tar.xz dir1 dir2 file1 file2
```

Comment: I see you are an Embedded Systems developer. Me too. Not an experienced one. Is there any stackexchange for us?

Comment: Hi Gilles, Could you please give the command to create `.rar` file using `7z` too please?